# Perforce: Add description to the existing changelist

Tags: perforce

I need to append some text to the description of already existing changelist in Perforce using Java.
What would be the most efficient way to do it?

I could think of

```
1. CL_content = p4 change -o <changelist> 
2. Then append the required text to the description
3. p4 change -i CL_content
```

But, it would not be suitable for very large changelists.

Any other way?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be suitable for very large changelists?

Comment: As it would require large amount of memory.

Comment: I think your suggested solution is the best one. I have done this in the past with large changelists and not noticed any performance problem.

Comment: I agree with Bryan. I do not see what would require so much memory. If you have evidence that such an operation will require large amount of memory, then post your code as you're most likely *doing it wrong*.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good. No other option to update a bulk of changelists at once.
Perforce should be able to take the load when you are doing one after other. I don't see any issues with it.